# Mysql query "WHERE 2 IN (`column`)" not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to execute a query where I can find one ID in a list of ID.

table `user`

```
id_user | name  | id_site
-------------------------
1       | james | 1, 2, 3 
1       | brad  | 1, 3 
1       | suko  | 4, 5
```

and my query (doesn't work)

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE 3 IN (`id_site`)
```

This query work (but doesn't do the job)

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE 3 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6)
```

Comment: What is type of id_site ?

Comment: WHERE column IN (..values..). 3 is not a column

Comment: `3` is not a value in your column - you have the values `"1, 2, 3"`, `"1, 3"` and `"4, 5"`, none of which are `3`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how `IN` works. I can't be bothered to explain why, just [read the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3,`id_site`)
```

Note that this requires your data to be `1,2,3`, `1,3` and `4,5` (ie no spaces). If this is not an option, try:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3,REPLACE(`id_site`,' ',''))
```

Alternatively, consider restructuring your database. Namely:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_site_links` (
    `id_user` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id_site` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`site_id`)
);
INSERT INTO `user_site_links` VALUES
    (1,1), (1,2), (1,3),
    (2,1), (2,3),
    (3,4), (3,5);
SELECT * FROM `user` JOIN `user_site_links` USING (`id_user`) WHERE `id_site` = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 2):

**NO!** <sub>For relation databases</sub>

Your table doesn't comfort [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (*"each attribute contains only atomic values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain"*) of a database and you:

- use string field to contain numbers
- store multiple values in one field

To work with field like this you would have to use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) or store data like `,1,2,3,` (note colons or semicolons or other separator in the beginning and in the end) and use `LIKE "%,7,%"` to work in every case. This way **it's not possible to use indexes**<sup>[[1]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)[[2]](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37564)</sup>.

[Use relation table to do this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#A_design_that_complies_with_1NF):

```
CREATE TABLE user_on_sites(
    user_id INT,
    site_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, site_id),
    INDEX (user_id),
    INDEX (site_id)
);
```

And [join tables](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, uos.site_id
FROM user_on_sites AS uos
INNER JOIN user AS u ON uos.user_id = user.id
WHERE uos.site_id = 3;
```

This way you can search [*efficiently*](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/11/23/full-table-scan-vs-full-index-scan-performance/) [using indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Comment: I would suggest adding `PRIMARY KEY (user_id,site_id)` to the `user_on_sites` table, to ensure you don't get duplicate links, but other than that you've said everything I wanted to say but much clearer XD

Comment: ... That's not what I said. What you've added does *nothing* useful and does not prevent duplicate links.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol my bad, I was looking for references for indexes not working on `find_in_set` and `like` (I was surprised that b-trees can work on `LIKE "<constant string>%"` expressions) and added wrong primary key.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are searching within several lists.

You need something more like:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE id_site LIKE '%3%';
```

However, that will also select 33, 333 and 345 so you want some more advanced text parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE IN clause is useful to replace many OR conditions.
For exemple

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

is cleaner than

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR id=3 OR id=4
```

You're just trying to use it in a wrong way.

Correct way :

```
WHERE `field` IN (list_item1, list_item2 [, list_itemX])
```

Comment: "reverse IN" (ie. ``WHERE value IN (`column1`, `column2`)``) is arguably haxy, but it works - I use it sometimes when there's two users involved in something, I might do ``WHERE 123 IN (`sender`,`recipient`)``